# Perform a segue between two UIViewControllers from third UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have segue between two `UIViewControllers` for example A to B. In another `UIViewController` (Say C), I have `UITableView` as a `subview` and when I click on one of the rows in this C, I want to perform segue between A to B. Is it possible?

I am presenting `C` for all UIViewControllers as a left-side slide menu using `MFSideMenu`.

When, I am trying `[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, segue is not performed and throwing an error.

Please suggest.

Comment: @rdurand, I am getting no segue with identifer error

Comment: Have you correctly set your segue's identifier in your storyboard ? Check the spelling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your `UIViewController` C, you have a reference to your `UIViewController *vcA`, you can try :

```
[vcA performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self];
```

I'm not completely sure this will work, but it's better than `[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]`, because you can't call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` directly on a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can not perform segue from UIViewController if this view controller does not contain this segue

instead, use `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:SEGUE_IDENTIFIER]`, then push to the destination view controller in the segue.

Good Luck

Comment: if we use that, I heard that every time new instance of UIViewController will be created and it wouldn't be safe..Please correct me if my thinking is wrong

Comment: you are right, so you can reference the destination view controller in the app delegate then call it when you need

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking something similar to @rdurands will work. If not, then you can setup a delegate method where UIViewController *vcA is a delegate to UIViewController *vcC. Then when vcC needs to perform a segue, it calls the delegate method which performs the segue and the delegate method is run from vcA.